# Excel formula to show only months that have ended

Tags: excel

I would like excel to show only the months that have ended. For the months that have not ended, I want the cells to be blank. I used this formula and it shows up #VALUE!. How do I fix this?

```
=IF( OR( IFERROR( (EOMONTH(A343,0)+1 > EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1)), ""), ISBLANK(A343) ), "", EOMONTH(A343,0)+1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Works as shown for me:

[image]

The formula you gave results in a blank as the month has not ended yet, while April has ended.

Answer (score 0):

The result set shows months blank which has not ended yet.
[image]